# Video Background - (php & css) - generating 404 error on page load - Wordpress Theme File Structure Help

Tags: page-template, 404-error

So i spent the entire day yesterday trying to achieve a full width responsive background video inside of a custom wordpress page template.

This is the bg-video code added to landing.php (my future landing page)

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="public_html/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/landingvid.gif" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="public_html/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/landingvid.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="public_html/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/landingvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I have also included

```
<base href="http://angeloconstantinou.com/" />
```

This is the Themes.CSS dealing with the video:

```
.fullscreen-bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.fullscreen-bg__video {
height: 300%;
top: -100%;
}
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.fullscreen-bg__video {
  width: 300%;
left: -100%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.fullscreen-bg {
background: url('../img/videoframe.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
display: none;
}
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the error messages telling me the file couldn't be located. If i follow the exact path it is trying to pull the files from, I can see the files sitting there. (picture 2)

[image: 404 error message]
[image]

**Things I have tried so far:**

- Moving landing.php out of a page-templates folder
- Moving source files into every other possible directory
- Using base URL re-write to stop Wordpress searching within a blog post ( i think i've got that right)
- Writing full route url instead of source src='landingvid.mp4'

I am not an expert with any of this and chances are I'm asking the wrong questions. Hopefully with all of the screenshots and snippets someone will be able to help.

the website & page in question is www.angeloconstantinou.com/landing.php - when i have this working I will set this as my static front page, with a button that leads to the usual front page / portfolio menu of the website.

Comment: Your paths should be `/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/` instead of `public_html/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/`

Comment: Thanks TheDeadMedic, I have deleted the other post and your fix is spot on. I can't up vote an answer for you as this is a comment. But this has answered everything.

Comment: Appreciate the cleanup. No worries, I can post it as an answer but you'll have to wait to mark it accepted.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using two <source> tags and download 2 videos? `MP4` is supported in all browsers..

Comment: If i'm honest, i've put this code together, by trawling through tutorials and various other forums. This was recommended for compatibility. If this isn't the case i guess removing the second source will only speed things up. (initially the tutorial called for three sources?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths should be:

```
/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/
```

... instead of:

```
public_html/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-pure/page-templates/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<source src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/page-templates/yourfile.pdf" type="text/pdf" />
```

The **bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')** function will send you to your **preset theme folder** where all your files are... 
It's a best practice in linking your files from your theme directory folder...

*Be aware that scripts( jQuery, jQUI, etc) should be linked in functions.php using wp_enqueue_script() function...*