# Wordpress generating 404 on .mp4 file in theme folder

Tags: themes, 404-error

I am trying to load a full width video on my homepage.  My situation is almost exactly like: 
[Video Background - (php & css) - generating 404 error on page load - Wordpress Theme File Structure Help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226303/video-background-php-css-generating-404-error-on-page-load-wordpress-t/226421)

However, I do have the path to my video set as:

```
<source src="/wp-content/themes/uf2016/assets/videos/videobg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

This is a stuck I have been on for a while and have tried various ways to call in the video but all result in a 404. What am I missing that is causing wordpress to not see this file?

Console output error

[image]

Console output error when using get_template_directory_uri()

[image]

Comment: can you show the console output error?

Comment: Yes, adding console output error to post now.

Comment: can you check if the file actually its there? can you try uploading an image using the media library and use the URL of the attachment detail.

Comment: Yes, I will try that and post back. This is driving me bananas.

Comment: Well it's a 404 error. It means that either the file doesn't exist, or access to it is blocked by server/.htaccess.

Comment: You bring up a point that I have been pondering. I will check .htaccess, I didn't set it up so I will comb through it again.

Comment: check the file permissions too the standard is 755 for folders 644 for files

Comment: Will do David. When I temp replaced the .htaccess file with the bare essentials it now returns a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: it could be 2 things, the .htaccess you put can be corrupted, or is the permissions files, you can delete the .htaccess then go to Settings -> Permalinks and click "Save Changes" WP will generate one for you.

Comment: Perfect David! Will do that now.

Comment: Could it be something as simple as the filename including uppercase characters? Certain server environments (UNIX) will return a 404 if you try to load a file without the correct letter casing.

eg: Videobg.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Using `get_template_directory_uri()` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` you can retrieve the url to your themes folder, and after that you just need to specify the path starting from there. Your code should look like this:

```
<source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/videos/videobg.mp4'; ?>" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: I've tried that, same error.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right path? Open the Console when loading the page and see what URL it's requesting.

Comment: Boris, I'll post screenshot of what happens when I change to template_directory_uri.   The path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method to call the http path to your mp4 file, to resolve this consider using one of the following wp functions :

```
get_theme_file_uri('assets/videos/videobg.mp4');

Or this : 

trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ).'assets/videos/videobg.mp4';
```

So your final code should look like the following snippet :

```
<source src="<?php echo  get_theme_file_uri('assets/videos/videobg.mp4') ?>" type="video/mp4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload your video in WordPress Media Library and copy video URL from them. You can check video URL from Attachment details.

Refer this : https://wordpress.org/support/article/media-library-screen/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).